# How do I make unity UI elements appear upon a value of slider being reached?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'd like a little pop up gui element to appear to let people know certain things are happening when a slider hits a certain value.

At the moment I have.

```
public void Update(){
    float t = animationTime;
    if (0.41f < t && t <= 0.6f)
    Debug.Log("this is where the pop up needs to show");
}
```

I've got a little text pop up, I'm unsure how to get it to show at this point. What would be the best way to get it to animate up, like a spring effect upon entering?

Comment: You don't need to use update, you should use the OnValueChanged(double) event. When the slider is moved the method is called, then you can check what is the value and do what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the Text object you want to enable. So in your class make a field `public Text textObject;` In your inspector you'll want to drag and drop the Text component onto the component you are creating.

Then in your code above where you have your Debug.Log you will want to use `textObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);`